# Adding custom module to freeradius v3.0.x

Tags: freeradius

I'm trying to add a custom modules to "freeradius-server" - version v3.0.x

I have folder named "rlm_custom" with files named "all.mk" and "rlm_custom.c",
I put it on "freeradius-server/src/modules/".

after sending command "make" and "make install", the modules are not included in ,"mods-available",

Any can help me about this

I've tried check "/usr/etc/lib" theres a file name "rlm_custom.la" and "rlm_custom.so"